# In what meaningful way can we talk about the generators of the super-Poincaré algebra being "spinors" or "4-vectors" because of their indices?

Tags: representation-theory, supersymmetry, lie-algebra, spinors, poincare-symmetry

It is often presented without much justification that the generators of the super-Poincaré algebra carry indices that imply they are elements of a representation space of the Poincaré algebra. In other words the indices on the supercharges, $Q_\alpha^I$, and the indices on the Poincaré generators, $M_{\mu\nu}$ and $P_\mu$, imply that there is some subtlety regarding their "transformation behaviour" when the super-Poincaré algebra is treated as a (reducible) representation space for the Poincaré algebra.

My question then is, what is the exact construction of this representation space? Presumably one needs some product of irreducible representations of the Poincaré algebra, namely a vector $(1/2,1/2)$ representation and a Weyl spinor $(0,1/2)$ representation, building to something along the lines of:

$$(1/2,1/2)\times (0,1/2)\times (1/2,0). \tag{1}$$

Once we have these it is sensible to give the generators of the super-Poincaré algebra these indices. However I have yet to see a text that does this in a way that is clear.

We have had some discussion about this in the hbar chat that was useful, but I thought I would ask it as a question on the main site in case it was of more general interest since it appears to have not been asked before.

Comment: For anyone interested there is actually some discussion about this on [the Wikipedia page of the super-Poincaré algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super-Poincar%C3%A9_algebra#SUSY_in_3_+_1_Minkowski_spacetime) which I stumbled onto recently.